No Tilde "~" in the swedish keyboard file
Is there any way of adding letters/signs to individual keys or function keys ?
Sine I have been looking for the Tilde ~ sign but i went through all 4 of the keylayouts in settings/keyboard and I can not find any key or key combination to write the Tilde sign.
To program an Function key would be OK or replace some other obsolete signs on the keyboard map

Have you looked into what the ASCII number for that symbol is?

Which version of Ubuntu are you running? And what physical keyboard it it, is there a key on the right side of Å? And how do you activate Swedish keyboard? What happens if you run setxkbmap se and try according to amar's answer?

There is no need to create anything.
In Swedish keyboard you can type tilde by pressing AltGr+¨ that is right Alt and the key after letter å
Please see the picture below:

